# How to send dynamic message(SMS)in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter... I need to send an SMS to all the students parents mobile number who are absent for the day in the format like "Dear Parent,your "student_name" is absent today. The students name are present in array. How to retrieve them one by one and send their names to their respective parents?

```
$name=array(); 
foreach($Result as $row) { 
  $students[] = $row['student_id']; 
  if($row['student_parent_phone']!="") 
     $mobile[] = $row['student_parent_phone']; 
  if($row['student_name']!="") 
     $name[] = $row['student_name']; 
} 
return array( 'students'=>$students, 'mobile'=>$mobile, 'name'=>$name );
```

Comment: you need to use loop for getting student name as per student status of class(present or absent). every time loop is executed, it takes student name and parent details (phone no) and send sms inside loop. this process is continue to all absent students. for more clear answer share your code.

Comment: where is your sms logic ?